# flutter how design circler bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter

please how can I make this flutter circler bottom navigation bar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M1JF.png)

Answer (score 0):

use this package: [circular_bottom_navigation](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_bottom_navigation)